# How can you tell whether two groups are homomorphic/isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

Suppose you have two groups, $G$ and $H$. I've been taught the following definitions:

"$G$ is homomorphic to $H$ iff there exists some function $\theta$ which gives the mapping $\theta : G \rightarrow H$

$G$ is isomorphic for $H$ iff, in addition to this, $\theta : G \rightarrow H$ is a bijection"

How are you supposed to know whether the function $\theta$ exists, or what it is?

Comment: In general, you're not. For example, what about the additive group of the real numbers and the additive group of the complex numbers, are they isomorphic?

Comment: There are many ways to find it but in general it requires some imagination. You for example have to either define it into existence or you'll have to use help theorems to prove it must exist, without specifically stating it.

Comment: "$G$ and $H$" are homomorphic" is not standard; I wonder where you were taught this? Given such $G$ and $H$, there is always at least one homomorphism between them, namely the trivial one that takes everything in $G$ to the identity in $H$, so the concept is not useful.

Comment: A homomorphism is required to "respect" the operations of $G$ and $H$, so your definition as stated is missing crucial fine print. Separately, as several people have pointed out, your definition of "homomorphic" is trivial; are you perhaps thinking of "$H$ is a _homomorphic image_ of $G$ if there exists a _surjective_ homomorphism from $G$ to $H$"?

Answer (score 2):

If two groups with binary operation $(G, \cdot)$ and $(H, \star)$ are homomorphic then there $\textit{exists}$ a mapping $\theta:G\rightarrow H$. More precisely, $G$ and $H$ are homomorphic if there exists a mapping $\theta$ such that

$\theta(a \cdot b) = \theta(a)\star \theta(b)$ for any $a,b \in G$.

Often we don't know what this mapping is, but we find one and show it satisfies this property (i.e., preservation of the group operation), to show that the groups are homomorphic, i.e., there exists a homomorphism from one group to the other. An isomorphism is just a bijective homomorphism (both injective and surjective). If two groups are isomorphic then for all intents and purposes they can be considered the same group, because they have the same group structure. The elements are just named differently.

Comment: Maybe you also want to mention that the term homomorphic is completely useless as any two groups will be homomorphic.

Comment: Why would any 2 groups be homomorphic?

Comment: @user2910074 Because one can always take the trivial homomorphism, as explained in another answer and in other comments.

Answer (score 2):

It is not easy, in general, to tell whether two groups are isomorphic. It is, however, quite easy to show that any two groups are "homomorphic."

Let $G, H$ be groups. Then I will define $\theta: G \to H$ by $\theta(g) = e_H$ for all $g \in G$, where $e_H$ is the identity element of $H$. Then for any $g, g' \in G$, $\theta(g g') = e_H = e_H e_H = \theta(g) \theta(g')$, so $\theta$ is indeed a group homomorphism.